# Are we allowed to reproduce an element that is similar to stack overflow's Tags box?

Tags: support, design, user-interface, copyright

I like the way the Tags box behaves, it would be useful for one of our projects (A survey asking for multiple words). So I started down the path or reproducing the behavior. I'm not stealing any code, but I wanna be on the up-and-up and my knowledge of how copyright works is kinda vague. So uh...am I allowed to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you are allowed to do that.

Concepts and ideas do not fall under copyright law, and the widget for tags is certainly not unique to the Stack Exchange network in any case; the [jQuery Tag-it library](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) implements something similar, for example.

You cannot copy the exact style (CSS) of the widget, technically speaking. But the way it operates is fair game.

Comment: Worth to mention the creator of that jQuery plugin is a [long time Stack Overflow user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/89373/aehlke). :)

Comment: @Shadow: Alex Ehlke is the current maintainer; the *creator* is [Levy Carneiro Jr.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1857713/levycarneiro), a not-so-long-time Stack Overflow user... :-)